# Google Apps Script alert not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function FindLastRowAndDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Math');
  ss.activate();
  var LastRow = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var Date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(LastRow, 1).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The Value for LastRow is ", LastRow, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);      
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The Value for Date is ", Date, SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

The first alert works fine except it shows 11.0 instead of 11 (like a simple alert without the title does). Any idea why?
The second alert fails for   Exception: The parameters (String,(class),ButtonSet) don't match the method signature for Ui.alert.
Why; its syntax appears identical to me?
Any clues/solutions gratefully received.

I've tried using const instead var, but that didn't make any difference

Comment: `Date` is a javascript object.  Change the name to something else like MyDate.

Comment: That didn't change anything, but thanks anyway

Comment: You edited it in 2 places right?

Comment: Of course; the declaration & the alert.

Comment: So now what is the error?

Comment: Same as my original post; 11.0 vs 11, & syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Description**

Apparently a Ui alert can not take a Date object.  You need to `.toString()` it or use Utilties.formatDate() to present the date value.

To remove the extra decimal digits use `.toFixed()`.

Note, it is customary to have the first letter as lowercase in variable and function names.  First letter uppercase is normally used for Object Class or global variables.

**Script**

```
function findLastRowAndDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Math');
  ss.activate();
  var lastRow = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var myDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(LastRow, 1).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The Value for LastRow is ", lastRow.toFixed(), SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);      
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The Value for Date is ", myDate.toString(), SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

**Reference**

- [Number.toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)
- [Date.toString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp)
- [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: @NigelHunt is this solves your question, please mark this as the answer.  That way others that have a similar problem know where to look.  Thanks.

Comment: It does answer the question, but I can't see how to mark it as such. Please can you do that for me?

Comment: There should be a check mark by my answer that only you can check.